# NSString drawInRect draws blank if first character is a new line character (\n)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, pdf-generation

I just noticed this behaviour. I am drawing a PDF with the following call:

```
[string drawInRect:renderingRect
              withFont:font
         lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping
             alignment:alignment];
```

Everything is fine except when the first character of string is a new line (\n) character. For example:

```
[@"Hello hello" drawInRect:renderingRect withFont:font lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:alignment]; // Draws "Hello hello"

[@"\nHello hello" drawInRect:renderingRect withFont:font lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:alignment]; // Draws nothing
```

Is there anything am I missing? It seems a bit odd to me that the method wouldn't print anything if the first character is a new line.

Also, `(CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode` has no problems when the first character is a new line character. It does the size estimation with no problems.

Comment: When i am executing your code it is not drawing anything only, i mean after executing the one code without \n?

Comment: @hussainShabbir Sorry, I couldn't understand your comment.

Comment: I mean when i am executing this [@"Hello hello" drawInRect:renderingRect withFont:font lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:alignment]; // Draws "Hello hello" it is not drawing anything for me. Is it complete code??

Comment: Are you sure your rect is large enought to contain more that one line? Try create the rect manualy, make sure that height is large and see is it works. Mabye you should encode your string before you draw.

Comment: @hussainShabbir This is not the whole code of course. There is also the part to create a PDF document, start a page and finalize the document. I left those parts out since it doesn't seem too relevant.  Maybe you could try drawing on a UIView?

Comment: @Greg I do create the rect manually. I tried specifying infinite width and height, still the same result. Can you elaborate more on the encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have started compiling the app with iOS7 and the problem doesn't happen anymore. So, it must have happened due to following configuration:

- Building the app with iOS6
- Running the app with iOS7 devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you use text encoding the two characters: 
`\n`
 will be draw but I believe you want to put line break instead. Try this code it works for me:

```
NSDictionary *attr = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:22], NSFontAttributeName,[NSColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];

NSAttributedString *text=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello hello" attributes: attr];

NSSize attrSize = [text size];
[text drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(X, Y)];
```

I think you can replace `drawAtPoint:`method with some method to takes rectangle as a parameter.

Comment: Where is the encoding part here? Also, your string doesn't have a new line in the beginning.

Comment: I misunderstand your question I thought you want to print \n character but I believe you want to print new line. Have you try this code above with \n on the front? Is it works fine if you put it in the middle of the string? If you want to encode you can use standard apple method like for example: newString = [oldString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; but id doesn't help it your example.